# Change order of categorical variable and reference category using lm

Tags: r, tidyverse, lm, texreg

I have an unordered categorical variable (event_time) with 5 different options `("future", "past", "prebirth", "never", "uncertain")` as a predictor variable, and I want to specify somehow to make `"never"` the reference category (ideally without transforming the variable). I'm just using lm and then `texreg::screenreg(list(m1, m2, m3)` to compare output for models with different outcome variables but this same predictor.

If there's a way to to rearrange the order that the categories show up in the model (perhaps within `screenreg`?) that'd be wonderful.

And an added bonus if this can all be done without dealing with transforming and factor variables (I know how to do this with relevel if the variable was a factor already)...thanks much.

Some data:

```
structure(list(yvar = c(4.43024525984776, -3.01051231657988, 
4.70993862460106, -2.03636967067474, -1.09802960848352, -1.16527740798651, 
5.6002805983151, -7.03524067599639, 1.02474010023752, 0.647438645180132
), event_time = c(NA, "Pre", "Future", "Time unknown", "Future", "Future", NA, 
"Never", NA, "Never"), race = c("Black", "Black", "White", "Black", 
"Black", "Black", "Black", "White", "Black", "White"), log_parent_income = c(4.0073333, 
NA, 3.8066626, 2.1972246, 0.69314718, 4.2484951, 3.9120231, 1.9459101, 
2.3025851, 3.8066626)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And then just doing a simple `lm(yvar ~ event_time + log_parent_income + race ...` model.

Comment: By far the easiest way to do this is by transforming the factor variable - I'm sure it's *possible* to do it otherwise, but a pain.  (For example, you could set up custom contrasts.) Can you clarify why that's *not* an acceptable/preferred solution? You can do it on the fly if you like, i.e. `lm(..., data= transform(orig_df, event_time=relevel(event_time, "never")))` ...

Comment: For the ordering in `screenreg`, how about the `reorder.coef` argument?  (Can we have a [mcve] ... ?)

Comment: I mostly just dislike dealing with factors (I am a Stata person typically and have never gotten the hang of factors). Added reproducible example to the question.

Comment: can you clarify how you want to reorder the categories in the output (e.g. what order, other than alphabetical-after-reference-level, do you prefer)? Is that separate from making "Never" the baseline level?

Comment: @BenBolker making "Never" the baseline is the real priority. But the ideal order they'd show up in the output would be "Future", "Pre", "Time Unknown"

Answer (score 3):

In base R, you can change the contrasts directly on the linear regression

```
 lm(yvar ~ C(event_time, base = 2)+ log_parent_income + race, data = df)
```

That is if you knew the base you want.

If you know that the reference level is the last one, then you can do:

```
 lm(yvar ~ event_time + log_parent_income + race, data = df, 
     contrasts = list(event_time = "contr.SAS"))
```

Of course this means that if you were to do the same for various variables, just change the options:

```
 options(contrasts = rep("contr.SAS",2))
 lm(yvar ~ event_time + log_parent_income + race, data = df)
```

This is assuming that `Never` is the last reference level. You can mess up with the `contr.treatment` base argument to set the reference to any number that you want

Lastly, you can write up a function that takes in the base argument as a string character:

```
C1 <- function (object, contr, how.many, ...) 
{
  base <- list(...)$base
  if(!is.null(base) &is.character(base))
      base <- match(base, levels(factor(object)))
  C(object, base = base)
}
```

Then you could use it as:

```
lm(yvar~C1(event_time, base = "Never"), df)
```

Is that not enough? You could change the contrasts argument by providing a function too. With this, the names will be maintained I believe

Comment: This is nice. I am continually amazed at how many **different** ways there are to set contrasts in R (not necessarily a good thing!): `C`, `contrasts<-`, `options(contrasts=...)`, `lm(..., contrasts=...)` (is that all?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will make you happy or not, but here goes.

A helper function that will be useful for reordering:

```r
match_pattern <- function(regex, target) {
    sapply(regex, function(x) {
        g <- grep(x,target)
        if (length(g)==0) return(NA)
        if (length(g)>1) stop("multiple matches")
        return(g)
    })
}
```

Fit the model. Here I'm using the `forcats` package because `fct_relevel` is less fussy about accepting a character vector (i.e. I don't need `relevel(factor(event_time), "Never")`.

```r
m1 <- lm(yvar~event_time,
         data=transform(dd, event_time=forcats::fct_relevel(event_time,"Never")))
```

If you like the tidyverse you can make it *slightly* more compact:

```r
dd %>% mutate(across(event_time, ~fct_relevel(.,"Never"))) %>%
     lm(formula=yvar~event_time)
```

Now `texreg::screenreg(m1)` will actually output the coefficients in your preferred order ("Future", "Pre", "Time unknown") because it *happens* to be alphabetical.  If you wanted to change the order to something else you could:

```r
ref_order <-  c("(Intercept)", "Time unknown", "Future", "Pre")
pp <- match_pattern(ref_order,names(coef(m1)))
texreg::screenreg(m1, reorder.coef=pp)
```

<s>While it would *theoretically* be possible to do what you want without touching the data set (by setting up a custom contrast), I think it would be considerably harder.</s> In the long run trying to work in a language without adopting its idioms can be tough — you might try figuring out what you don't like about factors and trying to address it (the `forcats` package can be helpful for some tasks).

Comment: I do indeed like the Tidyverse...and forcats seems to make things a lot easier. The texreg::screenreg code is also exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the help and the explanations, Ben!